# Using a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating the function Bricks(). It works the first time it is called, but when I call it later with another event, I get an error saying that Bricks() hasn't be defined. What could I be doing wrong?

Function Created:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        function Bricks() {
            var $container = $('#timeline-posts-wrap'); 
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector:'.post-wrap'
                });
            });         
        }       
        Bricks(); 
    });
</script>
```

Called Upon later:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".comment-button").click(function() {
            $(this).parents(".post-bottom").find(".commenting-area").toggle();          
                Bricks();           
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" You need to do more debugging and explain what precisely happens!

Answer (score 2):

Because the function `Bricks` is defined in closure scope(the dom ready handler) so it will be available inside that dom ready handler only.

If you want to use it in a different scope, you need to define the function in a shared scope, in this case you can use the global scope(window scope), that is define the function outside the dom ready handler

```
function Bricks() {

    var $container = $('#timeline-posts-wrap');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post-wrap'
        });
    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Bricks();
});
```

---

Another solution as suggested by @AlienArrays is to move the contents of both document ready handlers to one so that both of them will share the same closure scope

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function Bricks() {
        var $container = $('#timeline-posts-wrap');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.post-wrap'
            });
        });
    }

    Bricks();

    $(".comment-button").click(function () {
        $(this).parents(".post-bottom").find(".commenting-area").toggle();
        Bricks();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to reference your function globally, you must define it globally:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.Bricks = function () {

        var $container = $('#timeline-posts-wrap');

        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.post-wrap'
            });
        });

    };

    Bricks();

});
```

Note: there are better, cleaner ways to write the above code, but this serves as an answer to the question at hand.